# Manage datepicker dates with material ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have to date pickers, start date and end date. what I want to do with the end date is that if you choose the start date to be December 15 (for example) then when you choose the end date all the previous days to December 15 should be disable.

**The thing is that I don't know how to pass to my end date the selected start date.**

This is my code.

```
import React from 'react';
import DatePicker from 'material-ui/DatePicker';
import Divider from 'material-ui/Divider';

import cr from '../styles/general.css';


export default class DatePickers extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      startDate: '',
      endDate: ''
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event, index, value) {this.setState({value});}

  render() {

    const today = new Date();
    today.setDate(today.getDate() + 1);

    return (
      <div className={cr.container}>
        <div className ={cr.boton}>
          <Divider/>
        </div>
        <div className={cr.rows}>
          <div>
            <div>
              <DatePicker
                hintText="Start Date"
                minDate = {today}
              />
              <br/>
              <DatePicker
                hintText="End Date"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Any help on this??

Regards..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at [their documentation](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/date-picker) you can use `minDate` to set the value you need and `DatePicker` takes care of disabling unnecessary dates automatically for you.

`<DatePicker minDate={yourDateValue} />`

In order to manipulate dates, you can use `state` for example and, on every date change, you update it accordingly:

```
<DatePicker
  onChange={(_, date) => this.setState({ startDate: date })}
  value={this.state.startDate}
/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, the thing is that I don't know how to pass the start date value to my end date.

Comment: @kennechu I've updated my answer. Hope that helps :)

Comment: thanks again but I have some questions, what those (_, date) mean? I don't get the meaning of the underscore parameter in the piece of code you put...

Comment: @kennechu check material-ui documentation in the link I posted on my answer. The first argument is undefined :)